# Why should I be using Lighthouse with Pivotal Tracker

Tags: agile, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I've started using Pivotal Tracker and really enjoy it. I've also started looking at Lighthouse. Is there any value in using both systems with Tracker's Lighthouse integration? Should I sync *everything* from Lighthouse to Pivotal or keep bugs separate in Lighthouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lighthouse is a vanilla issue tracking system, along the same lines as [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/), [Github Issues](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation) et al, and is fine if all you want to do is maintain a list of bugs and features.

Pivotal Tracker is sold as an 'agile project management tool', and is geared towards teams who are specifically running an *agile development process* where development is done in sprints.  Tracker allows your team to estimate your stories in points and, over time, it calculates your team's *development velocity* which, in theory, allows you to accurately predict when features will be delivered.  This doesn't mean you can't use Tracker in the same way as Lighthouse (i.e. without worrying about points) - it will still work well for you like that.

Given this, I'd definitely use one system rather than a combination of both.  Having had experience of both I'd recommend Tracker, but this is of course personal preference and YMMV.